# find all comma delimited values from a varchar2 datatype column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, csv

I am not sure whether this is possible or not to find all the comma delimited values from a varchar2 datatype column.

```
id      test
----------------------
1        1
2        3,10,15,20
3        2
4        3,15
```

If my table is as above then i want to return only row 2 and 4 as below i.e. result of query should look like below:

```
    rownum       test
    ----------------------
    1        3,10,15,20
    2        3,15
```

Comment: What with data like `1 -1,2,3` and `2 - 2,3,4`? How result will look like?

Comment: The result should look like second table as shown in the question.

Comment: It is impossible to store comma-delimited values in a NUMBER data type column. It has to be character type.

Comment: Oh Yes, You are right. It is a varchar2 type.

Comment: @TusharBhaware Then do it the way I have shown `WHERE instr(TEST, ',') > 0`. Please mark it answered, would help others too. Not sure why a downvote though.

Comment: Where the ID value in output is being fetched, either for ID filed or test field.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, it is a rownum. Updated the question.

Comment: @TusharBhaware Is the answer not correct for you?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I haven't tried it yet. Once i try, I will mark as accepted if it is correct. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> find all the comma delimited values from a number datatype column.

It is impossible to store **comma-delimited** values in a **NUMBER** data type column. It has to be character type.

Simply use **INSTR** in the filter predicate:

```
SELECT ID, TEST FROM your_table WHERE instr(TEST, ',') > 0;
```

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 1 ID, '1' TEST FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 2 , '3,10,15,20' FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 3 , '2' FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 4 , '3,15' FROM dual
  9    )
 10  SELECT ID, TEST FROM DATA WHERE instr(TEST, ',') > 0;

        ID TEST
---------- ----------
         2 3,10,15,20
         4 3,15
```

`INSTR(test, ',')` looks for the occurrence of **comma** `,` in the delimited-string. `> 0` will filter those rows.

**NOTE :** The WITH clause is only to build the sample data for demonstration.

Comment: SELECT ID, TEST FROM DATA WHERE instr(TEST, ',') > 0; This query seems to be right, Why With clause is required there? Straight to be answer only.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam "*Why With clause is required there?*" Then how are you going to show a working demonstration as OP did not provide the table and data? We use WITH clause to build sample data and demonstrate a working test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by using REGEXP function. A regular expression is a powerful way of specifying a pattern for a complex search.
So query to get result specific to is as :

```
select id, test from Table_name where test REGEXP '[,]'
```

For more details regarding REGEX : Go to [dev.Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks for input, Now I have updated my answer hope it is describing well now.